# Changing the Shadow Color of a Disabled QComboBox also changes the color of Active Text

Tags: qt, qt4, qtstylesheets

I'm currently trying to change the style of of disabled QComboBox, including the shadow drawn behind the text. Annoyingly enough, it seems the text shadow cannot be styled in the style sheet, which would be my preferred solution, but that's not the issue at hand.

I've have managed to change the shadow color in my code using `setColor( QPalette::Disabled, QPalette::Light, QColor( #, #, # )` on the QComboBox's palette. While this "works". I come into the issue that the text color for the active state (but not the list view) also takes on that color, completely overriding changes made by the style sheet. I was under the impression that style sheet was meant to trump the palette.

Ideally, the fix for this would be a 100% style sheet solution, but google searches for me have had no positive results as far as setting the shadow color in the style sheet. I did find something about an `etch-disable-text` property, but that seems to only be psuedo science.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `setColor( QPalette::Active, QPalette::ButtonText, QColor( #, #, # ) )` on my palette before assigning it to by QComboBox resolves the issue, but I'm still looking for a style sheet solution.